# Storing doubles in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Alright, so I want to store values in an array. Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner bob = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] mylist;

        System.out.println("What is your first value?");
        mylist = bob.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is your second value?");
        mylist = bob.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Issue #1: I'm being told `mylist = bob.nextDouble()` should be `nextLine()`. Why is that if it is clearly a double?

Goal: I want to somehow store those values given into an array so that I could later pull them out. Can anyone help?

UPDATE

For Issue #1, it tells me that it cannot convert from `Double()` to `Double[]`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mylist` is an `array` of doubles, not a single `double`.

When you do `mylist = bob.nextDouble();` you are basically trying to make an entire array equal a single number.

You instead need to assign the number to a specific place in the array.

1. Initialize the array with the amount of elements you are going to store in the array:

   ```
   double[] mylist = new double[2];
   ```
2. Assign the double to a specific place in the array:

   ```
   mylist[0] = bob.nextDouble();
   mylist[1] = bob.nextDouble();
   ```

Comment: Why is the number 2 instead of one in new double[2];? Doesn't counting start from 0 as shown in mylist[0]?

Comment: @Code123 When you initialize the array, you put the amount of elements you want. You want 2 elements, not one. The first position happens to be [0] and the second is [1], but when you count the number of positions, you have 2.

Answer (score 5):

The error is because you are trying to assign a double value to array in the following statement:

```
    mylist = bob.nextDouble();
```

as mylist is defined as an array here:

```
    double[] mylist;
```

First you need to intialize your array:

```
    double[] mylist = new double[2]; // initialise array to have two elements
```

and then try to assign the array elements with the user input like this:

```
    mylist[0] = bob.nextDouble();
    mylist[1] = bob.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an array (which is a type of object). First, create an array large enough to store your `double`(s) (not `int`(s)). And store the values at appropriate indices. Something like,

```
Scanner bob = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] mylist = new double[2];
System.out.println("What is your first value?");
mylist[0] = bob.nextDouble();
System.out.println("What is your second value?");
mylist[1] = bob.nextDouble();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mylist));
```

Comment: Why do I need to put = new double[2]; ? What does that mean?

Comment: We create instances of objects with `new`. In this case, it's an array and we're creating an object that can hold two primitive values. See also [JLS-10.4. Array Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4).

Answer (score 3):

An array is not a double, you need to select an index :

```
double[] arr = new double[2];
System.out.println("What is your first value?");
arr[0] = bob.nextDouble();

System.out.println("What is your second value?");
arr[1] = bob.nextDouble();
```

Also, don't call an array a list, use CamelCase for naming your 
variables/methods/classes, and initialize the array. I recommend you reading a Java tutorial for working on the basics of the language.

Comment: I did that, but not it gives me this error: The local variable mylist may not have been initialized.

Comment: I renamed your variable from `mylist` to `arr`, because it's not a list. Don't copy paste code, understand its logic and use it to your need :)

Answer (score 0):

Better still, use a list with generics.

```
List<Double> myList;

myList.add(bob.nextDouble());
```

That way, you can add as many doubles you want to the list. So that you dont have to worry about the indexing.